# Convert JSON string array into Excel Columns

Tags: excel

I have a JSON data like this

```
{
"data":[
["File1","loaded","somedate"],
["File2","skipped","somedate"],
["File3","cancelled","somedate"],
["File4","loaded","somedate"],
["File5","loaded","somedate"],
["File6","cancelled","somedate"],
["File7","loaded","somedate"],
]
}
```

I am trying to load it into Excel sheet with each of those items in that string array as columns with headers

FileName, Status, Date

So I tried importing the file as JSOn in Excel and in power query and First
it looks like this

> data    List

Here I right click on list and selected **Into Table**

Then it created  a list like this

```
Name      Value
----------------
data      List
```

Then I clicked the two sided arrow button on Value header and selected Expand to New Rows which created a list like this

```
Name            Value
------------------------
data            List
data            List
data            List
data            List
data            List
```

Then the arrow header of value colum I choosen Expand to Rows

Which separated everything in string array into rows like this

```
Name              Value
---------------------------
data              File1
data              Loaded
data              somedate
data              File2
data              Skipped
data              somedate
.....
...
```

It was totally aginst I expected

My Requirement was

```
FileName             Status              Date
---------------------------------------------
File1                Loaded             somedate
File2                Skipped            somedate
.....
...
..
```

How can I accomplish that. Please help

Answer (score 1):

After importing, don't right click to table. Instead just click on "List". You will get 7 rows, each with a list.

Then click to table, choose delimiter = none. You will get a table with 7 rows, each with a list.

Then click the expand arrows, extract values, and select comma as the delimiter.

Then split column by delimiter = comma

Then rename the columns if you need to.

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\Kevin\Downloads\sample.json")),
    data = Source[data],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(data, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Converted to Table", {"Column1", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}, {"Column1.3", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image]